# error returned even for images used for training

Tags: google-cloud-automl

I am using AutoML Vision from Google Cloud Platform. After training all the images, I deployed the model.
The confusion matrix does not look great, but I am OK with that.
The problem is that for any image, the prediction shows a message "No Object".
I tried using the same image that was used for training and even such images are returned with no object error.

Comment: what was your training error? what did the model predict for the same image during training? are you feeding the images in _exactly_ the same way? Do you apply the same transformations?

Comment: When I followed all the steps mentioned in the quickstart, it worked correctly. 
https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/quickstart
However, when I use my own image data the model is built, deployed but does not return any prediction for any image. Even if I provide the same image that was used for training, I get "No Object" error. This is strange.

Comment: I did not pre-process the images. I guess that is the error. There is a reference to pre-process the images in the quickstart guide but I did not find the python script used trainer/preprocess.py

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/how-to-classify-images-with-tensorflow-using-google-cloud-machine-learning-and-cloud-dataflow

Comment: Here is screenshot https://testme162.s3.amazonaws.com/no_object.png

Comment: The image shown in that screenshot is one of the images used for training. So I guess I should not get "No Object" error.

Comment: not necessarily: the fact that a datum was in the training set does not imply the model _must_ process it correctly. The training error is not absolutely zero. Nevertheless, in your case I think it is "fishy". I suggest you dig into the "transformations" a bit more, this can really cause such problems

Comment: AutoML claims that it enables developers with limited machine learning expertise to train high-quality models. :)